# Degenerate Monge-Ampere equation on a bounded domain with $C^{2,1}$ boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

In the paper by Guan Pengfei: "C^2 a priori estimates for degenerate Monge-Ampere equations" https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077242669
Prof. P. Guan proved in Theorem 1 that the degenerate Monge-Ampere equation satisfying Condition (C) on a strictly convex domain $\Omega$ with **$\partial \Omega\in C^{2,1}$**, with homogenous boundary value $\phi=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, has a unique $C^{1,1}$ convex solution.

And I now have some problem about the  approximation argument used in the proof of Theorems 1 and 7.

In the statement of Theorem 1, one assumes the boundary $\partial \Omega \in C^{2,1}$. And Prof. P. Guan applied the  approximation argument to show that the solvability of the Dirichlet problem holds under the weaker assumption on the regularity of the boundary $\partial \Omega \in C^{2,1}$. However, the a priori estimates (e.g. Lemma 10, Lemma 11 ect.) used by the author to prove Theorem 1 require the assumption on the boundary $\partial \Omega \in C^3$.

**But I can not understand the approximate process in the proof of Theorem 1(see Pages 13 and 14) very well. Precisely, I do not understand why this approximate process works under the weaker assumption of $\partial \Omega\in C^{2,1}$**. I believe this is well understood, but it still confuses me.

Thereby, I would like to ask for  some expert to explain the detail why the existence works under the assumption of $\partial \Omega \in C^{2,1}$  rather than the assumption of $\partial \Omega \in C^3$ (as what the condition for the a priori estimates established in the same paper)?

Thanks!

Comment: The key point is that the estimates don't depend quantitatively on the $C^3$ regularity of the boundary, so you can approximate $\Omega$ with smoother $\Omega_k$ whose boundaries converge in the $C^{2,1}$ norm, and take the limit. You can probably do both approximations at once (letting $\varepsilon = 1/k$) or to keep it simpler, you could do the entire proof as written for $C^3$ domains, get *a priori* estimates, and finally do the domain approximation.

Comment: The actual steps of the approximation procedure would be very similar to the one for linear elliptic equations, which you can find in Chapter 6 of Gilbarg-Trudinger. (I don't have the book in front of me, so I can't give a more precise reference.)

Comment: @Stanley Snelson  Thanks very much for your helpful comment! I believe that the approximation procedure you informed me is a good approach.

Comment: But there is still a problem confusing me.
Firstly, I shall present my own understanding:
 the author verified that the approximating functions $f_{\epsilon,\rho}$ satisfy Condition (C) near the boundary
 $\partial \Omega$ such that one can obtain the  approximating Dirichlet problems (55) by letting $\rho \rightarrow 0^+$, that is,
$$ \det (D^2 u_\epsilon)=f_\epsilon  \mbox{ in } \Omega,  \mbox{   } u_\epsilon =0 \mbox{ on } \partial\Omega.$$

Comment: However, in my opinion, the author did not mention definitely what are the smooth exhausting domains used by himself (maybe I made the mistake here).
   Hence, in my opinion, it seems that the approximating process in the paper is different from that is presented in Gilbarg-Trudinger's book (see Chapter 8, probably, Theroem 8.34). Precisely, the approximating Dirichlet problems (55) in the paper are still defined on $\Omega$, rather than on certain  smooth and strictly convex exhausting domains of $\Omega$ itself. That is the part which confuses me. Thanks!

Comment: This sort of approximation is commonly left implicit, which one could argue is a bit sketchy, but on the other hand, it's tedious to write down and no new ideas are involved. Having said that, I agree the requirement that each $\Omega_k$ be convex makes things somewhat tricky.

Comment: Let me make clear that I haven't read the paper very carefully. There could be a much better explanation for why you don't need to worry about the $C^3$ norm of the boundary.